# Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, project-reactor

New to reactor so I apologize if it isn't clear. I have a class which runs a repetitive process every 5 minutes (using: `Flux.interval(Duration.ofMinutes(5))`). Every 5 minutes, I ssh into some of our on prem linux machines and execute a bash script and record the output. Then I save that output to a DB. This works fine for a while but then I get:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached`.

The java program is running on a docker container and when I look at the logs, I see `io-executor-thread-<some-thread-number>`. This `some-thread-number` goes to about 250 before I get the OOM error. Here is my code for reference:

```
@PostConstruct
    private void pollMachines() {
        Flux.interval(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                .map(this::getAllMachines)
                .flatMap(name -> process1(name)
                        .map(this::process2)                                                
                        .doOnError(throwable -> LOGGER.info("Some error happened with {}", name))
                        .onErrorResume(throwable -> setOfflineStatus(name))
                )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .subscribe();
    }
```

Here is the exception:

```
 07:03:49.854 [io-executor-thread-256] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
backend     | reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
backend     | Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
backend     |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
backend     |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:798)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:937)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1354)
backend     |   at io.micronaut.scheduling.instrument.InstrumentedExecutor.execute(InstrumentedExecutor.java:42)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncSupplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1714)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFuture.java:1931)
backend     |   at io.micronaut.data.runtime.operations.ExecutorAsyncOperations.update(ExecutorAsyncOperations.java:152)
backend     |   at io.micronaut.data.runtime.operations.ExecutorReactiveOperations.lambda$update$12(ExecutorReactiveOperations.java:194)
backend     |   at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.CompletableFuturePublisher$CompletableFutureSubscription.request(CompletableFuturePublisher.java:78)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:238)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
backend     |   at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.CompletableFuturePublisher.subscribe(CompletableFuturePublisher.java:49)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromPublisher.subscribe(MonoFromPublisher.java:63)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
backend     |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
backend     |   at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$1.doOnNext(Publishers.java:248)
backend     |   at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onNext(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:56)
backend     |   at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.CompletableFuturePublisher$CompletableFutureSubscription.lambda$request$0(CompletableFuturePublisher.java:89)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
backend     |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
backend     |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Is there a way I can avoid this?

Edit: After it is done polling the 20 or so machines on 1 thread, the next polling session starts on another thread.
Edit: removed process3. Assume I'm only doing 2 processes per machine

Edit3: If I can re-phrase the question: Is there a way I can do the above processes every 5 minutes without running into the OOM exception

Comment: Why do you need to run a new process every 5 mins since it is clear the previous one hasn't ended? Why not have one process?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question? Let's say the ***getAllMachines*** returns 20 machine names. For each of those machines, I run 2 processes (Each process executes a bash script on the machine). I guess I could simply have 1 process and one bash scirpt instead of two. But that still doesn't solve the problem that every polling session, a new thread is created?

Comment: @stark I removed 1 process. Assume I'm only doing 2 processes per machine

Comment: By default, Flux.flatMap allows 256 concurrent executions. You cab specify an optional `concurrency` parameter to reduce allowed simultaneous operations. Note also, 256 concurrent ops does **not** mean 256 threads. Are you manually creating threads in process1 or process2 functions ? Or are you using an elastic scheduler in the calling code ?

Comment: @amanin No, I'm not creating any threads in either processes. This time I ran it, the exception occured again but it was not 256 but 310.
 ```[io-executor-thread-310] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
```

Comment: @amanin - yes, I'm using an elastic scheduler. Edited the code in the original question to show that

Comment: By analysing the stack trace, I wonder if the `io-executor` is not managed by micronaut itself, and maybe it is micronaut that starts too many threads. But anyway, try to force flatMap concurrency parameter to a low value (let's say 10 to test). I think it could be enough to lower the overall backpressure.

Answer (score 0):

- The thread count is too much, use thread pool instead
- The vm argument: “-Xss” is set a a large value?
- The memory of JVM is too small, set bigger if neccessary